# Rails 3 model valid when it should not be

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone tell me why my test keeps failing when I try to confirm uniqueness of the email attribute in my model. When I test this in the Rails console, it works correctly, but when I run the unit tests in the console, it fails with this error message:
[image]

This is my model:
[image]

And here is the unit test that keeps failing:
[image]

The reason the unit test keeps failing is that it says that invalid_user is valid when it shouldn't be. Can someone please help me figure out why this is failing -- it's getting on my nerves that I can't figure it out lol?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `name` and `email` fields should be database fields, not `attr_accessor`s. Perhaps you meant to make this `attr_accessible` instead?

Comment: Thanks that worked! I accidentally typed the wrong thing, I knew it was something simple. I'll accept your answer in 8 minutes when it lets me lol.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
:uniqueness => true
```

I don't see the true part in there.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, it seems that when you provide a hash to the uniqueness key, the `:uniqueness => true` is implicit.